# HTML image doesn't loud from GOOGLE CLOUD

Tags: html, google-cloud-storage

I have minimal knowledge of coding but I just spent the past 6 hours trying to resolve this issue.

[Go here](https://00e9e64bacc3daf62e03966fff513f687c1da85d19410d086a-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/gen-newsletter/o/Newsletter.html?qk=AD5uMEt6B53cGILTUyG2vO-msOj65ZyKKjGAnTB1cKHuPjMA0SgsBkk9BKypetNTD9w1VtrQbVkf-d6SEIlbm5dzqMflVmh9QcfC2IyVGcUFnr4LMRHp5atFLJ5DnoPSty6icuQ_mbAFZoGkqNanJh7vQW09KnfcnIJz2P06e-2BhTV8UlgczEOkRINOG-ni5BDrTYt8dqWeoXXCXxXFrY9PfYExZd9RDCL04BhjirHiVputDwc4TpZ_ybVSyNV1C2X9BVo7aPg-2e-GglZNSWw46E5iIIfXcCJIfnWMhcH72BKSk6BsKA0KLU7jNVzkWqCWiiTKY5ZePDlKPGy1Zs1lX8YfzC1yepCZzEa9LeojvEnQOhE4VNDE4Mv88F4etCQq26KyZQPZFaxcl704hlud0UGrv8x3PYHF0ZZT5uzlOVeRbWQGuTbFsZ3B5VVFcnBFjnXZrrSpxbChkdjhTGjp8FZFjvDGLi_zl0uPwBfVzqZ6QAJCovr7rvzDHySJ_Ws5UK9X4wRxu7DI2bgRqQ27mrU_y5VXZHrI632oe9H8QrwLbCmVpHxvBgCEQfsIdVwCNgc8XemFwNTf7nFiUWANajNfgnMQo007idh9hL224akPjq3rfslvdURVFC9s3I_AbiUkL_5Zd67vBuaBw6BozgNLrLpT8PS2iR0TSlrOT3dcW4IKY1a-BdKxsSJQ0_V4i-0WzKdX_oIN9k6k8T94a2Gr307ob7eyU_7q1AIhOYZOMHl3uf-JREOuLuo7Ebv1ja3AEBw-zx-IipxFSOTFG-Ox8qQKVg) to see the image I am trying to have load.

If I am suppose to chance the SRC lines, how and where do I do that?

The HTML image loads perfectly from my computer.

Comment: I get this when I go to the link {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"lockedDomainExpired","message":"Locked Domain Expired"}],"code":401,"message":"Locked Domain Expired"}}

Answer (score 0):

Like what @mlegg said, I get the same error when trying to go to your link. It looks like that is no longer a valid URL or there is some form of security on it so it's only accessible from your computer (since you said it works from your computer?).

It could also be getting pulled from your browser cache if it was a good URL at one time. Try doing a Shift + Refresh of the page or purposely clear your cache.

If you have the image locally you could try uploading to a different web based repository and src it from there.

Just to cover all bases, I trust you know how to put an image on a web page using the `img` tag:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
```

You might also want to try a different image that you know is available and accessible. You can use the URL above for lorempixel.com or you can scrounge up a different image from a Google Images search.